# Unable to Dissect L2TPV3 in Wireshark

Tags: tunnel, wireshark-dissector, l2tp

I can view L2TPV3 in decode as but dissection not working out while analyzing log in Wireshark.
Expect to see tunneled data mapped and could see in Wireshark.
Anyone came across L2TP decoding on Wireshark

[image: data not dissected]
[image: Encode as have no help]

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

By disabling CDHL and decode as l2tpv3 ( with Current option as Ethernet), we can decode it.

However this dissection is not retained. You need to do it again once you restart Wireshark.

[image: DecodeAs]